# How do you prevent users on your network from configuring network interface connections on your network without your consent or knowledge?

Tags: terminal, network, wifi, airport

As owner/admin of home wifi network with EERO Pro 6 router I'm seeing in macOS Monterey 12.3.1 interface network connections being configured without my consent or knowledge. What disturbs me besides believing it's two teen nephews is my devices' Mac addresses are being used as interface connections.

I believe someone is using ethernet Mac terminal commands to setup ifconfig and also manipulating the arp and ip addresses.

Is there anything I can do in Mac or iOS that can help stop this?

Comment: Except changing wifi password.

Comment: Hi @PCMac are you saying they getting onto your MAC (how?) and setting things up, OR they are connecting to WiFI (in which case can't you use MAC address filtering [only allow your address??] OR block their addresses??